Running code after resuming from withCheckedContinuation
I am wondering about implications of running a code after resume from checked continuation and I couldn't find any resources for that. Example:
func doSomething(value: Bool) {
    print(value)
}

func myAsyncMethod() async -> Bool {
    withCheckedContinuation { continuation in 
        continuation.resume(returning: true)
        doSomething() // <---
    }
}


I understand that it's not the best way to do it, but I'm trying to understand the issues with it (if there are any). Anyone any ideas?

It really depends on what doSomething does. If it mutates state that the code that is awaiting the continuation accesses then you could have a race condition

You must use await with withCheckedContinuation. so why you are not placing doSomething() after await withCheckedContinuation

You will have rase conditions if modify something after continuation.resume and await witchCheckedContinuation, so it's not thread safe.

@excE as mentioned in the question I know this is not the best way to write it and I'm not asking about a best way to write it. I'm asking about the implications or pitfalls of this solution purely to understand the mechanics behind it.

tl;dr
There is nothing technically invalid with your particular example, but this (anti)pattern of continuing execution of additional code after satisfying the await exposes one to certain risks, limitations, etc., outlined below.

The main concern is that this violates a core principle of Swift concurrency: When you await, the current execution context is suspended until the async work is done. The expectation is that when the await is satisfied and execution resumes in the caller’s function, that the work that we had previously await’ed is done, but letting doSomething continue to run violates this assumption.
Consider:
func myAsyncMethod() async -> T {
    let result = await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        someLegacyFunction { (value: T) in
            continuation.resume(returning: value)
            doSomething(with: value)
        }
    }
    doSomethingElse(with: result)
    return result
}

func doSomething(with value: T) { … }

func doSomethingElse(with value: T) { … }

There are several concerns:

You have no assurances about the order of execution of doSomething and doSomethingElse, much less whether they might even run in parallel.

You have no way of knowing when doSomething is done. In fact, in extreme cases, myAsyncMethod could actually return before doSomething finishes.

You have no way of cancelling doSomething.

Swift concurrency’s “cooperative thread pool” makes assumptions about how many threads it can create (limited to the number of processors on the device, in order to avoid over committing the CPU), and by tying up a thread while doSomething continues to execute after the await is satisfied, this means that Swift concurrency’s assumptions may not be valid.
For more information, see WWDC 2021 video Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes: It doesn’t cover this issue, specifically, but it offers insights regarding the Swift concurrency threading model, the contract it imposes upon developers, etc.

In your example, you are not doing anything substantial in doSomething, but it would be easy for some future developer to add code in doSomething that could introduce problems.


The long and short of it is that this is anti-pattern that unnecessarily exposes you to certain risks that are easily avoided by simply making the resume(returning:) the last thing that the awaited withCheckedContinuation does. In your particular example, there are unlikely to be any egregious problems, but it is easy to construct examples that lead to very unusual behaviors.

For example, consider the following, where a wraps legacy completion-handler-based method, b, in a continuation, but calls c after resuming; and a calls d after the await of the checked continuation:
class Experiment {
    let poi = OSSignposter(subsystem: "Experiment", category: .pointsOfInterest)

    func a() async -> Int {
        let state = poi.beginInterval(#function, id: poi.makeSignpostID())
        defer { poi.endInterval(#function, state, "\(result)") }

        let result = await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            b { value in
                continuation.resume(returning: value)                            // warning: should really do this *after* calling `c`
                self.c(with: value)
            }
        }

        d(with: result)
        return result
    }

    func b(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
        let state = self.poi.beginInterval(#function, id: self.poi.makeSignpostID())
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            completion(42)
            self.poi.endInterval(#function, state, "\(42)")
        }
    }

    func c(with value: Int) {
        poi.withIntervalSignpost(#function, id: poi.makeSignpostID(), "\(value)") {
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2) // we would generally never Thread.sleep`, but it is here for illustrative purposes; usually we would `Task.sleep`, which is non-blocking, but your example was using synchronous methods, so I am giving synchronous example
        }
    }

    func d(with value: Int) {
        poi.withIntervalSignpost(#function, id: poi.makeSignpostID(), "\(value)") {
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
        }
    }
}

When I profile that with Instruments, that results in a returning before b or c finish, c and d can run in parallel, all of which is likely to be expected behavior, introduces races, etc.:


So, needless to say, a more idiomatic pattern would be to make the parallelism of c and d explicit (presuming that was the intent), and move the call to c outside of the completion-handler closure for b:
func a() async -> Int {
    let state = poi.beginInterval(#function, id: poi.makeSignpostID())
    defer { poi.endInterval(#function, state, "\(result)") }

    let result = await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        b { value in
            continuation.resume(returning: value)
        }
    }

    await withDiscardingTaskGroup { group in
        group.addTask { self.c(with: result) }
        group.addTask { self.d(with: result) }
    }

    return result
}

That results in:

Now, a satisfies the contract with the caller that the await of a will not return until everything is done. And we can now add cancellation support with c and d, too.
Probably needless to say, if c and d were really this slow, we would refactor them to be non-blocking async functions. But the above was merely for illustrative purposes, only.

Exactly what I was looking for and couldn't find anywhere. Many thanks!
